# how to set constraint for uicollectionview so that it adjusts with all devices

Tags: ios, iphone, uicollectionview, constraints

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RYXiI.png)/Users/seedoo/Desktop/Simulator Screen Shot 28-Jul-2017, 1.33.59 PM.png
/Users/seedoo/Desktop/Simulator Screen Shot 28-Jul-2017, 1.34.37 PM.png

The gaps between the cells is less in iPhone 5s device than in 6s.Please let me know how to solve this issue.Thanks in advance.

Comment: for objective c or swift ?

Comment: objective c for the Xcode version 8.3.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this : make changes in all methods as per your needs

**Objective C**

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    return  CGSizeMake(collectionView.frame.size.width/2 -5, 135); // 2 is indicates number of cell in sigle row
}

- (UIEdgeInsets)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout insetForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section{
    return UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0);
}

- (CGFloat)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section{
    return 10.0f;
}

- (CGFloat)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout minimumLineSpacingForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 10.0f;
}
```